# How to get the text value of a Webix radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, webix

How to get `value` of the Webix ui.radio option? The `getValue()` method returns only ID os the selected one, as well as the first parameter in `onChange`. Is this possible at all? Thanks.

The sample:

```
{
  view:"radio",
  label:"uiRadio",
  options:[
    { id:1, value:"Test 1"},
    { id:2, value:"Test 2"},
    { id:3, value:"Test 3"}
  ], 
  on:{ onChange:function(newV){ 
    webix.message(this.getValue()+"  "+newV)
  }}
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/3e1adc6f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty but this is what I came up with:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"radio",
  label:"uiRadio",
  options:[
    { id:1, value:"Test 1"},
    { id:2, value:"Test 2"},
    { id:3, value:"Test 3"}
  ], 
  on:{ onChange:function(newV){ 
    var textValue = this.data.options
                  .filter(function(el) {return el.id == newV})
                  [0].value

    webix.message(newV + ": " + textValue)
  }}
});
```